# Sublime text 3 custom snippets not triggering

Tags: php, wordpress, sublimetext3

[image]I have just created sublime text snippet for PHP Wordpress loop. But it's not triggering while I was pressing tab.

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
 if(have_posts()): ?>
    <?php while(have_posts()): ?>
        <?php the_post(); ?>
        <?php the_title(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <!-- <tabTrigger>wp_loop</tabTrigger> -->
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>source.php</scope>
</snippet>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove commented line of **tabTrigger**

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
 if(have_posts()): ?>
    <?php while(have_posts()): ?>
        <?php the_post(); ?>
        <?php the_title(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>wp_loop</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>source.php</scope>
</snippet>
```

Comment: can you post screen shot of your current working file?

Comment: Ok I just add screen shot of my php file

Comment: please add <?php open tag and then try.

Comment: God dang, I feel like a goof for not thinking of uncommenting it. Thanks.